# Django's MonthArchiveView returns "Table 'mysql.time_zone' doesn't exist"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to view the archive with the following URL:

```
example.com/2019/06
example.com/2018/11
```

However, when accessed, 
 `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'mysql.time_zone' doesn't exist")`  is returned.

If i change `USE_TZ` in settings.py to `False`, the error goes away and i can access it normally, but I don't want to False.

urls.py

```py
path('<int:year>/<int:month>', ArchiveList.as_view(month_format='%m'), name='archive_list'),
```

views.py

```py
class ArchiveList(MonthArchiveView):
    model = BlogPost
    template_name = 'blog/post_list.html'
    date_field = 'created_date'
    month_format = '%m'
    year_format = '%Y'
    allow_future = True

    def get_month(self):
        month = super(ArchiveList, self).get_month()
        return month

    def get_year(self):
        year = super(ArchiveList, self).get_year()
        return year
```

models.py

```py
class BlogPost(models.Model, HitCountMixin):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    main_image = FileBrowseField("mainimage", max_length=200, directory="media/uploads/thumbnail/",
                                 extensions=[".jpg", ".png"], blank=False, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('SubCategory', verbose_name='category', default=3, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=33, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=108, default='', blank=False)
    content = FroalaField(default='', blank=False, null=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=False)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    hit_count_generic = GenericRelation(
        HitCount, object_id_field='object_pk',
        related_query_name='hit_count_generic_relation')
```

settings.py

```py
USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

What should I do now?

Comment: Can we see ```BlogPost``` model? You surely have a ```datetime``` field which need to be provided with ptz info.

Comment: which django version are you using?

Comment: @EmilioConte
I edited the question.

Comment: @Lavish
It's 2.2.1.

Comment: check that when you create your BlogPost the field ```created_date``` don't use a naive date. As you have blank=True, you need to add tzinfo=pytz.UTC when you create it. (import pytz first)

Comment: @EmilioConte
I checked `created_date` in DB, it was not native time. default is also False.

Comment: I don't think default can be False if you have USE_TZ set to True. In running server console don't you have warnings about **naive datetime**?

Comment: @EmilioConte
Oh, sorry. Type missed. `default=timezone.now` and `blank=False`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
The cause was that mysql's time zone was not UTC.

First, check time_zone.

```sql
mysql> show variables like '%time_zone%';
+------------------+--------+
| Variable_name    | Value  |
+------------------+--------+
| system_time_zone | JST    |
| time_zone        | SYSTEM |
+------------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If it's not UTC, read time zone information first.

```sql
$ mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql
```

and write these information to `~/etc/my.cnf`

```sql
[mysqld_safe]
timezone = UTC

[mysqld]
default_time_zone = UTC
```

Then restart mysql and done!

```sql
$ mysql.server restart

Shutting down MySQL
.. SUCCESS!
Starting MySQL
. SUCCESS!
```